# SuiteScript2.0 - Transforming Opportunity to Sales Order does not set Shipping Address Correctly

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to automate creating a lead, opportunity and sales order in one click of a button. The code below is how I am achieving this on a suilet. Everything get created and set perfectly expect for the Shipping Address on the Sales Order. For some reason the shipping address of the sales order is getting set to custom and only entering the State and Zip Code. I'm pretty sure I don't create an address for the sales order and feel like it should default to the default shipping address on the customer in the same way the billing address does. I have given the data.saleorder data.

```
function submitdata(data){
    var leadid = createLead(data);
    var opportunityid = createOpportunity(data, leadid);
    var salesorderid;
    if(data.salesorder) {
        salesorderid = transformRecordAndSetNewValues({
            from : {
                type : record.Type.OPPORTUNITY, 
                id : opportunityid
            },
            to : {
                type : record.Type.SALES_ORDER
            },
            values : data.salesorder,
            ignoreMandatoryFields : false,
        });
    }
    return {
        leadid,
        opportunityid,
        salesorderid,
        success : true
    }
}

function transformRecordAndSetNewValues(data){
    var objRecord = record.transform({
        fromType : data.from.type,
        fromId : data.from.id,
        toType : data.to.type,
        isDynamic : true,
        defaultValues : {
            customform : Number(data.values.customform)
        }
    });
    setRecordValues(objRecord, data.values);
    var recId = objRecord.save({
        ignoreMandatoryFields : data.ignoreMandatoryFields
    });
    setRecordForm({
        recordid : recId,
        form : data.values.customform,
        type : data.to.type
    });
    return recId;
}

function setRecordValues(objRecord, values)
{
    //Loop Fields And Add Values
    for(var key in values){
        log.debug(key, values[key])
        if(key == "shippingaddress" || key === "billingaddress"){
            createAddress(objRecord, key, values)
            continue;
        }
        //if(key === "type") continue;
        var value = values[key];
        value = testForBooleanAndConvertToBoolean(value)
        value = testForDateAndConvertToDate(value)
        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId : key,
            value : value
        })
    }
}

{
    "lines": [
        {
            "item": {
                "id": "1234",
                "sku": "ANSKU",
                "pricelevels": {
                    "1": "118.09091",
                    "6": "82.66364",
                    "7": "47.23636",
                    "9": "112.19",
                    "10": "106.28",
                    "11": "100.38",
                    "12": "94.47"
                },
                "taxcode": {
                    "text": "GST",
                    "value": "7"
                },
                "taxrate": "10.00",
                "displayname": "An Item Descripton",
                "description": "An Item Descripton",
                "type": {
                    "text": "Inventory Item",
                    "value": "InvtPart"
                },
                "model": ""
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "pricelevel": {
                "value": "1",
                "text": "BASE PRICE"
            },
            "rate": "118.09091",
            "amount": "118.09",
            "taxcode": "GST",
            "taxrate1": "10.00",
            "tax1amt": "11.81",
            "grossamount": "129.90"
        }
    ],
    "customform": 101,
    "formtype": true,
    "department": "7",
    "location": "1",
    "terms": "7",
    "timeslot": "2021-01-28",
    "shipmethod": "1234",
    "id": "123456"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transform to the sales order, set the 'entity' field.

Comment: I tried doing this and got an invalid field error.

Comment: "{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_RCRD_TRANSFRM","message":"You have entered an invalid default value for this record transformation operation.",

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This worked for me:                                                                     
    var newRec = record.transform({
        fromType: record.Type.OPPORTUNITY,
        fromId: 53493,
        toType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
        isDynamic: true
    });

    newRec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'entity',
        value: 5185
    });

    newRec.save();

Comment: I'll copy that code exactly and see what happens :)

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Thank you :D :D